# Menu with parents, children and or siblings pages display

Tags: navigation, wp-list-pages, child-pages

[Here](http://smeekens.live.addsite.nl/u-als-patient/afspraak) you see the parent menu selected in the horizontal navbar. I already have that working. I need a sidebar like they have with the same parent indicated plus children when they exist
. 
At the moment I have some great code thanks to [Michael's feedback at WordPress Stack Exchange on an earlier question here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45537/load-parent-pages-when-there-are-no-child-pages/45540#45540). But that code does not show the parent above the children pages nor children pages above the siblings. 
Any ideas how can I adjust this code made by Michael:

```
<?php                  
    $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0&depth=2');                   
    if ($children) { ?>                   
        <ul id="three-menu">                   
        <?php echo $children; ?>                   
        </ul>                   
        <?php } //ends (if($children)//
    elseif($post->post_parent) { //if no children, try to get parent page and show siblings pages including the page itself
        $siblings = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&echo=0&depth=1');                  
        if ($siblings) { ?>                   
              <ul id="three-menu">                   
            <?php echo $siblings; ?>                   
            </ul> 
    <?php } //ends if($siblings)// ?>                  
        <?php } else { //optional: if no children and if no parent, then show all top level pages
        $pagelist = wp_list_pages('title_li=&echo=0&depth=1');                   
            if ($pagelist) { ?>                   
                <ul id="three-menu">                   
                <?php echo $pagelist; ?>                   
                </ul>
    <?php } //ends if($pagelist)// ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

The WordPress Codex page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_current_Page_with_its_ancestors_and_children seems interesting, but I have not figured it all out just yet..

**Update:**

I added children to a depth of two  with the first `if` statement. That helps loading the children and siblings at a permalink level like: http://domain.com/top-level-page/. I just need to do some styling and rework the next to levels.

**Update 2 CSS Solution**

With some help I do have a menu that works quite well using `wep_list_pages` and some CSS. This is basically a CSS solution.

```
 <div id="home-menu">

                     <div class="wplp_menu">
                        <ul id="top-level-sidebar">
                     <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
                        </ul>
                     </div>

                </div>
```

and CSS:

```
li.current-page-ancestor a, li.current-menu-item a 
 {
    color:#146BBB; //#0D55A8;
}

ul.children .current_page_item a:link, 
ul.children .current_page_item a:visited {
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    width: 250px;
}


.wplp_menu li{
list-style:none;    /*blends out list dots,can be removed if done somewhere else*/
}

ul#top-level-sidebar {
    background: #5097EA;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 50px;
    float: left;
}

.wplp_menu .page_item a {
display:none;   
}
.wplp_menu .current_page_ancestor a,.wplp_menu .children .current_page_item a,.wplp_menu .current_page_item li a  {
display:block;
}

.current_page_item a {    /* CSS for active item*/  
font-weight:bold;
}
.current_page_item li a {
font-weight:normal;  /* Resets the above for its children */
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `wp_nav_menu()` for this?

Comment: As in a WordPress 3.0 widget menu? Well, as the setup was initially simple, as I use pages only and I thought it would be nice to have it auto-generated I went for this. And thanks to some help I got pretty far. Another large issue is that I have different menu displays per level (parent, child, sibling). I show children now and siblings when there are and if there are no children or siblings I show the standard `wp_list_pages` How would I do that using `wp_nav_menu()` ?

Comment: You can add menus with the function mentioned by @Mamaduka ↑ without any widget. Just place the template tag and fill it with the needed args.

Comment: @ kaiser. As I have been at it with this menu on and off for two weeks now and need it to function like the site mentioned I doubt I can simply create this. I would appreciate some guidance. Will look into `wp_nav_menu` again of course and see how I can convert all the added code plus make changes to make it look like the sidebar on the mentioned site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a partner developer I went for a CSS solution. The solution has been added to question above. It just hides all page items at first with `display:none` and then shows the items I need. The pages list is loaded with needed indentations using `wp_list_pages('title_li=');`

Comment: Yeah, I was playing with various plugins for a while ([Advanced Menu Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-menu-widget/) is OK) until I realised it's probably far easier in CSS.